# Почему кнопка растягивается по высоте?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Что происходит с кнопкой?
Кнопка почему-то растягивается по высоте, не могу понять что на нее так влияет.

```css
.button{
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 9px 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center; 
}

.block_about-us{
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:60px;
 margin-bottom: 67px;
 font-size:34px;
}

.about-us__title{
 color:#000;
 font-size:33px;
}

.about-us__quote{
    padding-top: 12px;
    color: #969696;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.about-us__text{
 color:#969696;
 padding-top: 26px;
 font-size:17.2px;
 font-style:normal;
}

.block_advantages{
 float:left;
}

.empty-advantages{
 float:right;
}

.advantages_icons{
float:left;
width:33px;
margin-right: 16px;
position:relative;
}

.advantages_icon-eye{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:20px;
 background:url(../img/fa-eye.png);
}

.advantages_icon-brush{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:31px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 76px;
 background:url(../img/fa-brush.png);
}

.advantages_icon-heart{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:27px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 164px;
 background:url(../img/fa-heart.png);
}


.advantages__content{
 float:left;
 width: 482px;
}

.advantages__name{
 text-transform: uppercase;;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 font-size: 16.25px;
 
}

.advantages__description{
 font-size: 17px;
 letter-spacing: 0.11px;
}

.advantages__item+.advantages__item{
     margin-top: 18px;
}

.advantages-button{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding:10px 30px;
 border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages block_advantages ">
    <div class="advantages_icons ">
     <span class="advantages_icon-eye"></span>
     <span class="advantages_icon-brush"></span>
     <span class="advantages_icon-heart"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__content ">
     <div class="advantages__item">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       1. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       2. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       3. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">View more</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: а что именно должно происходить ? И с каким элементом ?

Comment: @nosferatu-id  <a class="button" href="#">View more</a> . Кнопка почему-то растягивается по высоте, не могу понять что на нее так влияет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как работает float:](https://learn.javascript.ru/float#float-algorithm)

> При применении этого свойства происходит следующее:
>
> - Элемент позиционируется как обычно, а затем вынимается из документа    потока и сдвигается влево (для left) или вправо (для right) до того
>     как коснётся либо границы родителя, либо другого элемента с float.
> - Если пространства по горизонтали не хватает для того, чтобы вместить    элемент, то он сдвигается вниз до тех пор, пока не начнёт
>     помещаться.
> - **Другие непозиционированные блочные элементы без float ведут себя так, как будто элемента с float нет, так как он убран из потока.**
> - Строки (inline-элементы), напротив, «знают» о float и обтекают    элемент по сторонам.

1. Если нужно, чтобы кнопка отображалась снизу, то, как правильно [написал @Vladimir Rodichev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966083/191745), нужно убрать `float` со второго блока, чтобы кнопка "видела" второй блок и позиционировалась относительно его, или, как вариант, добавить для нее свойство `clear:both;`.
2. Если нужно, чтобы кнопка была справа, достаточно добавить для нее `display:inline-block;` или `float`, чтобы кнопка "увидела" другие блоки с `float`.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 9px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

.block_about-us {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 67px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.about-us__title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 33px;
}

.about-us__quote {
  padding-top: 12px;
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.about-us__text {
  color: #969696;
  padding-top: 26px;
  font-size: 17.2px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.block_advantages {
  float: left;
}

.empty-advantages {
  float: right;
}

.advantages_icons {
  float: left;
  width: 33px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.advantages_icon-eye {
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../img/fa-eye.png);
}

.advantages_icon-brush {
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  background: url(../img/fa-brush.png);
}

.advantages_icon-heart {
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 164px;
  background: url(../img/fa-heart.png);
}

.advantages__content {
  float: left;
  width: 482px;
}

.advantages__name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  ;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 16.25px;
}

.advantages__description {
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.11px;
}

.advantages__item+.advantages__item {
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.advantages-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages block_advantages ">
  <div class="advantages_icons ">
    <span class="advantages_icon-eye"></span>
    <span class="advantages_icon-brush"></span>
    <span class="advantages_icon-heart"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="advantages__content ">
    <div class="advantages__item">
      <div class="advantages__name">
        1. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
        2. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
        3. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="button" href="#">View more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо убрать `float` из блока:

```
.advantages__content {
    /* float: left; */
    width: 482px;
}
```

Comment: +1 - пока искал более-менее приличную цитату забыл написать данный вариант ответа))

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, `.button` так растягивался из-за `float: left` в `.advantages__content`, но это можно легко решить если добавить пару строчек для `.advantages.block_advantages`

```css
.advantages.block_advantages {
    display: flex; /* Так кнопка не будет растягиваться */
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.button{
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 9px 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center; 
}

.block_about-us{
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:60px;
 margin-bottom: 67px;
 font-size:34px;
}

.about-us__title{
 color:#000;
 font-size:33px;
}

.about-us__quote{
    padding-top: 12px;
    color: #969696;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.about-us__text{
 color:#969696;
 padding-top: 26px;
 font-size:17.2px;
 font-style:normal;
}

.block_advantages{
 float:left;
}

.empty-advantages{
 float:right;
}

.advantages_icons{
float:left;
width:33px;
margin-right: 16px;
position:relative;
}

.advantages_icon-eye{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:20px;
 background:url(../img/fa-eye.png);
}

.advantages_icon-brush{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:31px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 76px;
 background:url(../img/fa-brush.png);
}

.advantages_icon-heart{
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:27px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 164px;
 background:url(../img/fa-heart.png);
}


.advantages__content{
 float:left;
 width: 482px;
}

.advantages__name{
 text-transform: uppercase;;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 font-size: 16.25px;
 
}

.advantages__description{
 font-size: 17px;
 letter-spacing: 0.11px;
}

.advantages__item+.advantages__item{
     margin-top: 18px;
}

.advantages-button{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding:10px 30px;
 border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages block_advantages ">
    <div class="advantages_icons ">
     <span class="advantages_icon-eye"></span>
     <span class="advantages_icon-brush"></span>
     <span class="advantages_icon-heart"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__content ">
     <div class="advantages__item">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       1. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       2. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="advantages__item ">
      <div class="advantages__name">
       3. Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="advantages__description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">View more</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: судя по верстке автора предполагается наличие первого блока(иконки) слева, а не сверху. По текущему варианту предлагаемого Вами решения проще `float` убрать, `flex` не нужен вообще.